# Trying to add Items to a Dialog, but they don't get displayed

Tags: java, javafx-8

First time asker, so please excuse any missing/wrong-placed Information and of course my bad english. Gotta say that as a german. ;)

Simple and short, I try to add `Nodes` into a `Dialog` by using
`dialogPane.getChildren.add()`

```
Code:

The Class signature:

public class VerteilDialog extends Dialog<Void>

Declaration of the needed items:

private Label _jlVersionNum;

private TextField _tfVersionNum;

private Label _jlSonstiges;

private TextArea _taSonstiges;

ButtonType btAbbrechen = new ButtonType("Abbrechen", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
ButtonType btOk = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(btAbbrechen);
getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(btOk);``

And initialization of those in the contructor:

_jlVersionNum = new Label("Versionsnummer:");
_tfVersionNum = new TextField("4.10.x");
_jlSonstiges = new Label("Sonstiges:");
_taSonstiges = new TextArea();
_jlEinDatum = new Label("Einsatz am:");

And I add the Items like this:

getDialogPane().getChildren().addAll(_tfEinDatum, _jlVersionNum, _tfVersionNum, _jlSonstiges, _taSonstiges);
and Show the dialog
showAndWait();
```

Calling the Dialog happens here:
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

```
public class MainKlasse extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        new VerteilDialog();
    }

}
```

I'd expect the items to be added properly without further Problems, but (and that's why I am actually here):

The Dialog is displayed without further Errors or any exceptions, but it's empty apart from the Buttons, "Ok" and "Abbrechen".

**Edit: Added call of `showAndWait();` that I forgot while writing the question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, I found a solution.

`getDialogPane().getChildren.addAll()` does not add Nodes so that they get visible. One should use a Pane to add Nodes to and set the Pane as Content by using `getDialogPane().setContent`